# Printing A linked List - Access Violation C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a linked list which takes several input files, then it put them into a linked-list to print them later on.

I implemented a print function but it does not work well and gives access violation error. I tried to debug, unfortunetly I could not find the root of problem.

Error Line in the function:

```
cout << ptr2->command + " ";
```

Run-Time Error :

> First-chance exception at 0x00DAC616 in the file.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDE1.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "strutils.h" 
using namespace std;

struct Commands;

struct Functions
{
    string fname;
    Functions *right;
    Commands  *down;
};
struct Commands
{
    string command;
    Commands *next;
};

Functions *head;
Functions *temp;
Commands *temp2;

void StreamToLinkedList(ifstream &inputfile)
{
    string s;
    getline(inputfile, s);
    temp = new Functions();
    temp->fname = s.substr(0, s.length());
    temp2 = temp->down;
    while (!inputfile.eof())
    {
        getline(inputfile, s);
        temp2 = new Commands();
        temp2->command = s.substr(0, s.length()-1) + ",";
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    inputfile.clear();
    inputfile.seekg(0);
}
void printLinkedList()
{
    Functions *ptr = head;
    Commands *ptr2;
    while (ptr != nullptr)
    {
        cout << ptr->fname << endl;
        ptr2 = ptr->down;
        while (ptr2 != nullptr)
        {
            cout << ptr2->command + " ";
            ptr2 = ptr2->next;
        }
        cout << endl;
        ptr = ptr->right;
    }   
}
int main()
{
    string file, key, s;
    ifstream input;
    cout <<"If you want to open a service (function) defining the file," << endl
         <<"then press (Y/y) for 'yes', otherwise press any single key" << endl;
    cin >> key;
    ToLower(key);
    if (key == "y")
    {
        cout << "Enter file the input file name: ";
        cin >> file;
        input.open(file.c_str());
        if (input.fail())
        {   
            cout << "Cannot open the file." << endl
                 << "Program terminated."   << endl;
            cin.get();
            cin.ignore();
            return 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            StreamToLinkedList(input);
            head = temp;
            temp = temp->right;
        }   
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Cannot found any input file to process" <<endl
             << "Program terminated."<< endl;
        cin.get();
        cin.ignore();
        return 0;
    }
    do
    {
        cout<<  "Do you want to open another service defining file?"<<endl
            << "Press (Y/y) for 'yes', otherwise press any key" <<endl;
        cin >> key;
        ToLower(key);
        if (key == "y")
        {
            cout << "Enter file the input file name: ";
            cin >> file;
            input.open(file.c_str());
            if (input.fail())
            {   
                cout << "Cannot open the file." << endl
                     << "Program terminated."   << endl;
                cin.get();
                cin.ignore();
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                StreamToLinkedList(input);
                temp = temp->right;
            }
        }
    } while ( key == "y");
    cout << "-------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl
        << "PRINTING AVAILABLE SERVICES (FUNCTIONS) TO BE CHOSEN FROM THE USERS"   << endl
        << "-------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl << endl;
    printLinkedList();
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the code of the error ?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What did you try to debug?

Comment: Do you really have to implement your own linked list? **vs** std::list<T>

Comment: For first question, I debuged it because I had to make sure that it is really working; for the second, I have to implement my own linked list.

Comment: 0xCDCDCD ... is typical for Microsoft VC Debug version fill of uninitialised data. This is extension, in normal "non debug" C++ such area will have random value.

Comment: Should I initialize these pointers to nullptr?

Comment: There are many code paths through your program. It's not clear which one you are trying to debug. Please remove code that is not executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TO ANSWER**

Your print function is ok. The way you create and manage your lists is what's wrong, probably due to the fact that **you never initialize** your `Functions.right` and `Functions.down` fields, so your linked list is linking to invalid memory. Well, you don't actually *link* your list.

Some of your assignments such as `temp2 = temp->down` and `temp = temp->right` don't mean anything because these fields were not initialized and because you are overwriting these variables (`temp` and `temp2`) with new objects afterwards.

Also, you have duplicate code. You are reading from files, in the exact same way, in two distinct places. The issue is that your code is wrong so you have double the errors to fix. And the only apparent reason for code duplication here is that you want to show different messages for the first time a user enters input and the nth time.

I'd suggest placing this code in its own function. Otherwise find a more efficient way to use the conditionals/loops so you don't have so much duplicate code.

---

**NOTES**

I have a "few" things to note on your code. The LinkedList is implemented in two classes called `Functions` and `Commands`. I know that you want to have a *list of functions* and each function has a *list of commands*, but you have to learn to separate your program's domain from other functionality.

**IE:** A `LinkedList` is a container of objects (of any kind). A `Function` and a `Command` are specific things you made for your program that have nothing to do with linked lists themselves. From a conceptual point of view a `Function` contains `Command`s, but not necessarily through a `LinkedList`, or a `map`, or an `array`, etc.

Your code needs a separation of concepts, see how much clear it would be

```
// Linked list of functions
Functions list;

// No need to comment this one
LinkedList functions;
```

(Let's not argue the lack of a templated type)

Also, unless it makes sense to use the plural to name a class you should almost always use the singular (`Functions` vs `Function`). That's because when you instantiate a class you will have **one** object/instance, so using the plural for the type can be misleading. Consider the following declarations,

```
Function someFunction; // This is a single function
Functions someFunction; // Is this one function or multiple functions??

List< Function > functions; // This is a list of functions
List< Functions > functions; // Is this a list of lists of functions???
```

You should make a single class called LinkedList (Hint: use templates if you can to make it more reusable). Then if you were to separate the implementation of functions and commands from linked lists, you could make something like,

```
template <class T>
struct LinkedList {
    T* obj;
    LinkedList<T>* next;

    LinkedList() : obj( nullptr ), next( nullptr ) {}
};

struct Command {
    string cname;
};

struct Function {
    string fname;
    LinkedList<Command> commands;
};
```

And now you would declare your list of functions like this,

```
LinkedList<Function> functions;
```

Since each `Function` has its own list of `Command`s, you have a list of lists and you don't have to manage each list independently as in your current implementation. Of course, your list still needs an interface (and memory management) but that's not in the scope of this question.

**EDIT:**

Initialize your pointers to nullptr when they won't point to anything.

```
temp = new Functions;
temp->right = nullptr;
temp->down = nullptr;
```

Or usa a default constructor,

```
struct Functions {
    ...
    Functions() : right( nullptr ), down( nullptr ){}
};
```

And then initialize like,

```
temp = new Functions();
```

Comment: @Oguz You're in SO. You can search all around for template usage. Edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

your problem with access violation is that new is not by default zeroing the memory it allocates,
so the pointer inside the last struct is pointing to a random value.

```
temp2 = new Commands; // this memory is not initilized to zero
temp2 = new Commands(); // this memory is initialized to zero, (all elements is set to 0)
```